# How do I load predefined bins with quantities into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I am working through a stats textbook, some of the questions have pre-calculated bins with frequencies. I have been using `pd.cut` when I have the underlying data but here it is not the case. For example

| Bin | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 105-109 | 2 |
| 110-114 | 5 |
| 115-119 | 6 |
| 120-124 | 8 |
| 125-129 | 8 |
| 130-134 | 1 |

How do I load this into Pandas / numpy as a frequency table?

How can I obtain the same output as `value_counts` with `bins` parameter?

```
x = np.random.randint(20, 50, 50)
freq = pd.Series(x).value_counts(bins=7)  # or pd.cut(x, 7).value_counts()
print(freq)

# Output
(19.971, 24.143]     9
(24.143, 28.286]     6
(28.286, 32.429]     8
(32.429, 36.571]    11
(36.571, 40.714]     5
(40.714, 44.857]     3
(44.857, 49.0]       8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expect?

Comment: How do I load this into Pandas / numpy as a frequency table?

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected "frequency table"

Comment: it's in the question above.

Comment: So you question was just how to create a DataFrame? Loading from where? Are you going to type it every time you have a new dataset?

Comment: I edited your question to add an example for better understanding.

Comment: ok thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create the dataframe manually?

```
freq = pd.DataFrame({
    'Bin': ['105-109', '110-114', '115-119', '120-124', '125-129', '130-134'],
    'Frequency': [2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 1]
})
```

Output:

```
>>> freq
       Bin  Frequency
0  105-109          2
1  110-114          5
2  115-119          6
3  120-124          8
4  125-129          8
5  130-134          1
```

**Edit**

Use [`pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_breaks.html) to convert your strings as [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html):

```
# From the freq dataframe
bins = freq['Bin'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(bins[0], bins[1], closed='left')  # or 'right'
freq = pd.Series(freq['Frequency'].values, index=bins)
```

Output:

```
>>> freq
[105, 109)    2
[110, 114)    5
[115, 119)    6
[120, 124)    8
[125, 129)    8
[130, 134)    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: df = pd.cut(x,7).value_counts(). It provides bounded values for example a < x < b. in the example above it's simply a string rather than a bounding range. How would I create it with the bounding range?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it what you expect?

Comment: Yes it was, perfect